# log4cpp and odd console output

Tags: c++, log4cpp

I am trying to use log4cpp on my project.  But everytime I try to write a log message in addition to the log message going to the log file I also get this message to the console window.

```
/var/log/ngis/mixer.log.3
```

Here is the copy of the appropriate section of my log4cpp.properties file.

```
#  This is for the rolling file Appender, this will not send log info
#    to the syslog.
log4cpp.rootCategory=INFO, rootAppender
log4cpp.appender.rootAppender=RollingFileAppender
log4cpp.appender.rootAppender.fileName=/var/log/ngis/mixer.log
log4cpp.appender.rootAppender.maxFileSize=10MB
log4cpp.appender.rootAppender.maxBackupIndex=3
log4cpp.appender.rootAppender.BufferedIO=true
log4cpp.appender.rootAppender.BufferSize=100000
log4cpp.appender.rootAppender.layout=PatternLayout
log4cpp.appender.rootAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d[%p %c] %m%n
```

The data is going to the log file.  I have tried creating a file called /var/log/ngis/mixer.log.3 but that does not help.

if I change the .maxBackupIndex=3 to .maxBackupIndex=2 then the message changes to:

```
/var/log/ngis/mixer.log.2
```